# Using SVG map as basemap and interactive GeoJSON on top with Leaflet/OpenLayers?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, layers, svg

I have SVG map and GeoJSON file with cells. I need to combine them so the user can hover/click on cell and get some cell info like cellID in the console.

Currently using the angular-leaflet-directive Leaflet plugin and the SVG is rendered correctly, but the cells/GeoJSON are too small compared to the map. Here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

HTML:

```
    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demoapp">
<head>
    <title>Final</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="assets/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/angular-leaflet-directive.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/leaflet.css" />
    <script>
            var app = angular.module("demoapp", ["leaflet-directive"]);
            app.controller("GeoJSONController", ['$scope', '$http', '$log', 'leafletData', "leafletBoundsHelpers", function ($scope, $http, $log, leafletData, leafletBoundsHelpers) {
                var maxBounds = leafletBoundsHelpers.createBoundsFromArray([[-540, -960], [540, 960]]);
                angular.extend($scope, {
                    defaults: {
                        scrollWheelZoom: true,
                        crs: 'Simple',
                        maxZoom: 4
                    },
                    center: {
                        lat: 0,
                        lng: 0,
                        zoom: 0
                    },
                    maxBounds: maxBounds,
                    layers: {
                        baselayers: {
                            sanfrancisco: {
                                name: 'normalMap',
                                type: 'imageOverlay',
                                url: '../normalMap.svg?v=1',
                                bounds: [[-540, -960], [540, 960]],
                                layerParams: {
                                    showOnSelector: false,
                                    noWrap: true
                                }
                            }
                        },
                    }
                });

                // Get the countries geojson data from a JSON
                $http.get("../cells.geojson").success(function (data, status) {
                    angular.extend($scope, {
                        geojson: {
                            data: data,
                            style: {
                                fillColor: "white",
                                stroke: 1,
                                weight: 2,
                                opacity: 1,
                                color: 'black',
                                dashArray: '10',
                                fillOpacity: 0.7
                            },
                            maxBounds: maxBounds,
                        }
                    });
                });
            }]);
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="GeoJSONController">
<leaflet lf-center="center" geojson="geojson" defaults="defaults" layers="layers" maxBounds="maxBounds" height="100vh" width="100vw" ></leaflet>
</body>
</html>
```

I Tried with OpenLayers but its not working as well.

Comment: What's the root reasoning behind the `540`/`960` dimensions for the SVG? What are the range of coordinates of the GeoJSON geometries? I'm gonna bet the coordinate ranges won't match.